# Library to count number of objects in image?

Tags: python, theano, tensorflow

I'm reading a [paper](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2010/Lempitsky10b/lempitsky10b.pdf) on counting cells, humans, etc. Is there an off-the-shelf library for Python/Theano or TensorFlow I could use?

Answer (score 3):

I think the OP was asking for a specific library *for* Theano or TensorFlow that provides off-the-shelf functionality for object identification.

I would look first into `scikit image`, an image processing library for Python in the Scipy/Numpy stack. It has all sorts of edge detectors, blob detectors, shape identifications, color separations... Look at their [gallery](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/) of examples.

Btw, counting humans in a crowd may not be so trivial to automate...

Comment: You are correct that I am asking for a library. Thanks for your suggestion. Taking a look now...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are libraries for TensorFlow and Theano.

[Theano Library](https://github.com/Theano/Theano):  An [extensive tutorial](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/) for the Theano library is also available online.

[TensorFlow library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow): An in-depth [official tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/index.html) of TensorFlow.  (Highly recommend, if you're going with TensorFlow)

In addition, I would also like to suggest you to have a look at this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/694/11097) regarding open source Python deep learning libraries.

Answer (score 1):

To see what you can do considering the size(area) of objects, the android app [PHOTO COUNT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exa.pgomes.photocount&hl=pt_BR) do the job using opencv 3.1 library.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question...  TensorFlow is OpenSourced, [here is a tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html)

To import the TensorFlow library, all you need to do is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```