# Does Tensorflow support a Decision Tree Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, decision-trees

I am trying to implement decision tree classifier to classify my data set. I am using Python. Now it is easy to implement in scikit learn, but how can I implement this in tensorflow.

Comment: Even if Decision Trees were offered for TensorFlow(which they don't), I wouldn't suggest using it. There is so much technical overhead with getting a tensorflow model going compared to sklearn...
Pick the right tool for the job! <https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically I guess `TensorFlow` does not support decision trees. I quote from [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12921/28175),

> *This is a big oversimplification, but there are essentially two types of machine learning libraries available today, `Deep learning`
>   (CNN,RNN, fully connected nets, linear models) and Everything else
>   (SVM, GBMs, Random Forests, Naive Bayes, K-NN, etc). The reason for
>   this is that deep learning is much more computationally intensive than
>   other more traditional training methods, and therefore requires
>   intense specialization of the library (e.g., using a GPU and
>   distributed capabilities). If you're using Python and are looking for
>   a package with the greatest breadth of algorithms, try scikit-learn.
>   In reality, if you want to use deep learning and more traditional
>   methods you'll need to use more than one library. There is no
>   "complete" package.*

You can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43031536/5120235) that there are other learning algorithms implemented in `TensorFlow` which are not deep models.

You can take a look at [here](https://terrytangyuan.github.io/2016/08/06/tensorflow-not-just-deep-learning/) for tracking algorithms implemented in `TensorFlow`.

Comment: I'm torn on this: I'm aboard with the reasoning of your quote, but on the other hand: Random Forrest is a kind of tree learner.

Comment: @SvanBalen I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Tensorflow supports random forrest (as documented by the link you gave), random forrest is a special kind of tree learner. So even though Tensorflow doenst seem to support common learners (CART or C45) and even though it is primarily a library for deep learning, and even though I too would use sklearn, it technically supports a tree learner, making your statement false.

Comment: @SvanBalen I thank you if I really have made a mistake for announcing me but I don't know where I'm wrong. I've said `TensorFlow` does not support decision trees, which is really the case. Which part I'm wrong?

Comment: TF supports random forest, random forest is a decision tree (a specific type at that), hence TF supports decision trees. But like I said: I'm torn at whether your statement is wrong: Technically it is, **but** for all *practical* purposes it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what I wrote on the [other post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/is-tensorflow-a-complete-machine-learning-library/12921#12921), TensorFlow does in fact have implementations of Random Forest and Gradient Boosting, in addition to other non-deep learning algorithms. The links can be found at that post.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that tensorflow is based on numerical methods (i.e., gradient descents). There is no gradient in tree-based methods. The exception is gradient regression tree.