# Best Javascript Modules for creating Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, javascript

After checking out this similar post for python: [Best python library for neural networks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/694/best-python-library-for-neural-networks), I was curious if the community had recommendations for JavaScipt modules for creating neural networks. I am transitioning from Python to JavaScript for work and have not found the same readily available modules that Python has or that have been developed to the same extent as Python versions (sklearn, keras, etc).

I have been working with the tf.js module.

So, what JavaScript modules are particularly helpful for neural network building?

Comment: isn't tf.js enough? It seems to supersede all other js libraries for NNs, since it is an engine in itself

Comment: tf.js has been useful, and I understand the engine part is beneficial, but I'm wondering if there are other modules with tools that people may prefer to use